# HTTP Status 500 – AbstractValueFactoryProvider Class not found

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey

I had follow the below solution to solve my problem.

[RESTFUL WS: pass more than 1 parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53258689/restful-ws-pass-more-than-1-parameter?noredirect=1#comment93401908_53258689)

However, I encountered another error:

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet
>   [jersey-servlet] threw exception
>
> Root Cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/inject/AbstractValueFactoryProvider

I find out that the class has not inside the latest Jersey download:

https://jersey.github.io/download.html

Currently the list of Jar file that I used are :

[image]

The current changes that I've made to my code are:

```
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;

@Path("{uuid}/{browserinfo}/{ipint}/{lat}/{longitude}/{sessionid}/{spid}/{tr}"
            + "/{jsnum}/{fingerprint}/{methodset}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public int adaptiveAuth(
            @PathParam("uuid") String uuID, 
            @PathParam("browserinfo") String browserInfo, 
            @PathParam("ipint") long ipInt, 
            @PathParam("lat") double latiTude, 
            @PathParam("longitude") double longiTude, 
            @PathParam("sessionid") String sessionID, 
            @PathParam("spid") String spID, 
            @PathParam("tr") int tR, 
            @PathParam("jsnum") int jsNum, 
            @PathParam("fingerprint") String fingerPrint, 
            @PathParam("methodset") MethodClass[][] methodSet) throws SQLException{
```

Is there any idea on how to fix the problem?
If the latest version of Jersey is no longer support on AbstractValueFactoryProvider, what is the replacement of jar that I can use in order to make my code works?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't mix your Jersey versions. Make sure all the Jersey jars are all the same version. I see you added a jersey-media-multipart-2.1. Is 2.1 the version of Jersey you are using? If not, make sure you are using the right version. If you change it to a later version like 2.27, then you may also need to change the mimepull jar to 1.9.6

Comment: Hi Paul,
Thank you for your comment.
I have tried to use latest version of Jersey : [link]http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/2.27/jaxrs-ri-2.27.zip

And use jersey-media-multipart-2.2.7 and mimepull1.9.6-jar, but the Jersey still returning error: 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public

Comment: Why are you using jersey-media-multipart-2.2.7? Why specifically, did you choose that version? As far as the error, have you googled it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am using the latest Jersey version, so I updated the particular jar as per latest version.
I also change @PathParam to @FormDataParam and it works. 
I am able to view the wadl file. 
Now proceed to test the Web Service using SOAP UI.
Thanks